# How can I make a command be triggered when an item is throwed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to have a command that makes a item that when I throw it will freeze mobs for 100 s in a 200 block area (trigger a command). how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Have the following commands repeating, in this order:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add FreezeItem {Item:{id:"minecraft:ice",tag:{display:{Name:"Freeze"}}}}
/execute @e[type=Item,tag=FreezeItem] ~ ~ ~ /effect @e[type=!Player,r=200] slowness 100 50
/kill @e[type=Item,tag=FreezeItem]
```

You can change `{Item:{id:"minecraft:ice",tag:{display:{Name:"Freeze"}}}}` to the tags you want to identify the item by. Currently, it's a block of ice renamed "Freeze".

You can also change `/effect @e[type=!Player,r=200] slowness 100 50` to whatever command you want to activate when the item is thrown.

Comment: A screenshot always helps, could you add it?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek There's not really much to see, just three command blocks.

Comment: Some people don't even know how to get a command block :D Adding screenshots never makes things worse :-)